# Gnu screen: remap "c-a c-a" to send "c-a"

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I use GNU Screen on occasion, and my Emacs keybinding muscle memory is hard to overcome.  I know that I can send a control-a (i.e. "go to beginning of line") by hitting "c-a a", but I'm wondering if it's possible to remap the keybindings so that c-a c-a so that sends the c-a.

I've tried a simple "bind ^a ^a" in the `.screenrc`, but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

I suspect there's some way to do it with the combination of bind and bindkey, but the answer isn't obvious to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want:

```
escape ^a^a
```

or

```
bind ^a meta
```

(since `meta` sends the command character, i.e. here `^a`).

But since `^a` is typically more useful than `^z` in GNU Screen, you could use `^z` as the command character. This is what I do:

```
escape ^z^z
```

Comment: Both of these seem to work for me.  I hadn't ever seen used multiple windows within a single screen instance, and instead had been using multiple screen sessions with different `screen -S FOO` and `screen -S BAR` and various `screen -r <name>` commands to reconnect.  I can see the utility in the multiple window scheme.