# linux (gnu-) screen: remap Ctrl-a (default command key) to Alt-a in 'one go'

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts, gnu-screen, termcap

Looking for a way to remap `screen`s `C-a` or `^a` (default command) binding, to `Alt-a` or `^[a` by using an easy to memorize, one-go command / switch. I know this can be possible in 2 steps, but also only from screen itself - however, ideally I'd like to pass some parameter(s) to `screen`s command line, when firing it up.
What I'm looking for is something similar to `Tmux`s  command `set prefix M-a` (or rather somethin similar, since afaik `screen` doesn't understand such human-friendly syntax for Alt/Meta key).
It would be even better if I could remap this default `^a` to `AltGr-a`

Tried following:

```
1. $ screen  -e '\0033''\0141'
```

Values of those were taken from showkey:

```
$ # showkey -a                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    Press any keys - Ctrl-D will terminate this program                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    ^A        1 0001 0x01            < Ctrl-a                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    ^[a      27 0033 0x1b            < Alt-a yields 2 lines : first line                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
             97 0141 0x61            < Alt-a second line
```

where the first line was `C-a` key-press.
2nd and 3rd line was `Alt-a` *single, simultaneous* key-press. Screen sees indeed 2 chars (as is required by `-e` but fails to map them as per my expectation.

2. From inside screen, I was hoping to do be able to somehow leverage the `-k` option to `bindkey`, as per the example here in its [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/html_node/Bindkey.html#Bindkey), where it says:

> Command: bindkey [opts] [**string** [cmd args]]
>
> The argument ‘**string**’ is the sequence of characters to which an action
> is bound. This can either be a fixed string or a **termcap** keyboard
> capability name (selectable with the ‘-k’ option).

The problem is where to find the 'Termcap' entry for `Alt / AltGr` key.  `man termcap` shows nothing.

Also, maybe this [SE answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/158942/510467) would be helpful, but I haven't been able to figure out the right syntax

---

For those suggesting to switch to `Tmux` instead:

- I have to ssh on many different servers and its default keybindings are awkward to me, including changing windows, lack of `C-b C-b` jumping back to previous one (one has to use `C-b l` for this);
- no session locking
- my screen "muscle memory"
- and a few others issues, which I'll remember if need be ;)

**Even remapping** `AltGr` <-> `Ctrl` would be a good enough solution provided it doesn't involve any X-related programs, since the servers are `X` free (non X-polluted).

Answer (score 2):

I've often wondered about the choice of ^A as the command char for gnu screen as it's usefulness in readline etc. makes it a keypress I use fairly regularly.

Anyway, I use ^X instead (as it's not often used for anything else).

Add this to your .screenrc:

`escape ^Xa`

(from https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#index-escape-character):

> escape xy
>
> Set the command character to x and the character generating a literal
> command character (by triggering the meta command) to y  (similar  to the
> -e option).  Each argument is either a single character, a two-character
> sequence of the form ^x (meaning C-x), a backslash followed by an octal
> number (specifying the ASCII code of the character), or a backslash
> followed by a second character, such as ^ or \.  The default is ^Aa.
> ter, such as ^ or \.  The default is ^Aa.

Comment: Thank you for helping maintain my sanity! `Ctrl-a Ctrl-d ... Ctrl-d` is a very common sequence for me to change a command. By default, it will successively exit `screen` and any enclosing shells quickly rendering my terminal dead.